# Which VertexList types are valid for depth_first_search

Tags: c++, c++14, depth-first-search, boost-graph

When using a boost::vecS for VertexList in the adjacency_list boost::depth_first_search(Graph, Visitor) compiles and works correctly. When switching the VertexList type to boost::listS I receive the compiler error:

boost_1_65_0\boost\graph\detail\adjacency_list.hpp(2545): error C2182: 'const_reference': illegal use of type 'void

From this error I would gather that the boost::listS is not a valid type, however the BOOST CONCEPT checks pass.

If boost::listS is not a valid type for depth_first_search, why?

Below is example code demonstrating the issue. Switching from vecS to listS generates the above error. I am using Visual Studio 2017 and boost 1.65.0

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_concepts.hpp>


//typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::bidirectionalS> MyGraph;
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS> MyGraph;
using VertexType = boost::graph_traits<MyGraph>::vertex_descriptor;

BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT((boost::VertexListGraphConcept<MyGraph>));
BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT((boost::IncidenceGraphConcept<MyGraph>));
class dfs_visitor : public boost::default_dfs_visitor
{

public:

  void discover_vertex(VertexType u,  const MyGraph& g) const
  {
  }

  void finish_vertex(VertexType u,  const MyGraph& g) const
  {
  }

};

BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT((boost::DFSVisitorConcept<dfs_visitor, MyGraph>));

int main()
{
  MyGraph g;
  dfs_visitor vis;
  boost::depth_first_search(g, boost::visitor(vis));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: See also [faq #5](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/graph/doc/faq.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I love that you included the concept checks. A trick learned today.

The real answer is simple: the concept constrains the graph type. However, the other arguments add more constraints:

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/graph/doc/depth_first_search.html
(bold mine)

> **IN**: `vertex_index_map(VertexIndexMap i_map)`
>
> This maps each vertex to an integer in the range [0, num_vertices(g)). This parameter is only necessary when the default color property map is used. The type `VertexIndexMap` must be a model of Readable Property Map. The value type of the map must be an integer type. *The vertex descriptor type of the graph needs to be usable as the key type of the map*.
>
> Default: get(vertex_index, g). Note: if you use this default, ***make sure your graph has an internal vertex_index property. For example, adjacency_list with VertexList=listS does not have an internal vertex_index property.***

In other words, your graph is FINE. But you have to supply a vertex index.

**<kbd>[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bGeYOgxzruWyoTvB)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_concepts.hpp>
#include <numeric>

typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::bidirectionalS> MyGraph;
using VertexType = boost::graph_traits<MyGraph>::vertex_descriptor;

BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT((boost::VertexListGraphConcept<MyGraph>));
BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT((boost::IncidenceGraphConcept<MyGraph>));

struct dfs_visitor : boost::default_dfs_visitor {
    void discover_vertex(VertexType, const MyGraph &) const {}
    void finish_vertex(VertexType, const MyGraph &) const {}
};

BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT((boost::DFSVisitorConcept<dfs_visitor, MyGraph>));

int main() {
    MyGraph g;
    dfs_visitor vis;
    std::map<MyGraph::vertex_descriptor, int> index;

    // fill index
    for (auto vd : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(g))) {
        index.emplace(vd, index.size());
    }

    auto index_map = boost::make_assoc_property_map(index);
    boost::depth_first_search(g, boost::visitor(vis).vertex_index_map(index_map));
}
```

If you read closely, you can also satisfy it by passing a custom color map. This has the tiny advantage that there would be no need to initialize all elements to the default-initialized value:

**<kbd>[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/agvEQy5ElhQ2a48I)</kbd>**

```
int main() {
    MyGraph g;
    dfs_visitor vis;
    std::map<MyGraph::vertex_descriptor, boost::default_color_type> colors;

    auto color_map = boost::make_assoc_property_map(colors);
    boost::depth_first_search(g, boost::visitor(vis).color_map(color_map));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The examples are great and will work nicely with the existing graph I am traversing.